# iphone development: how to handle fbwebdialogs pop-up buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, dialog

In my app I use FBWebDialogs to sen app request to facebook friends and I do it successfullty. My problem is I cant handle FBWebDialogs pop up windows button. In the code below I can detect X button and cancel button but when I select send button it still gives the log `NSLog(@"User canceled request.");` I am using the codes exactly given in the facebook documentation. What is my mistake?

```
[FBWebDialogs
         presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
         message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
         title:nil
         parameters:params
         handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
                 NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
             } else {
                 if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                     // User clicked the "x" icon
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     // Handle the send request callback
                     NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                     if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                         // User clicked the Cancel button
                         NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                     } else {
                         // User clicked the Send button
                         NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                         NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }];
```

And I have parseURLParams function like that:

```
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *val =
        [[kv objectAtIndex:1]
         stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [params setObject:val forKey:[kv objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is a common problem because of a bug in SDK 3.5 so I updated the sdk from 3.5 to 3.5.1 and the problem solved.