# Facebook Invite friends , in my iOS app .. what the mistake in my code?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, invite

I would like to make invitation button to invite my facebook friends to use my app. I looked at and tried many code . the best in providing interfaces and control to choose more than one friend was mentioned here 
[iphone development: how to handle fbwebdialogs pop-up buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822148/iphone-development-how-to-handle-fbwebdialogs-pop-up-buttons)

I am using Facebook SDK 3.5.2 
The log shows the request ID ... but nothing received to my friends 
plz , can you identify where is the mistake in this code?

I appreciate your help

Comment: I think its about the permissions on Facebook app centre . what are the permissions (User & friends- extend) I have to set to allow invite friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to publish something in the friends timeline you need to ask for the publish_actions permission.

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/